# Drop pdf file to sharepoint in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, pdf, spsite

what's the best way to accomplish this task? (new to sharepoint)

Do we need to install sharepoint on webserver in order to use sharepoint.dll/spsite object or just adding the reference to sharepoint.dll in asp.net is sufficient ?

If yes then what features of sharepoint need to be installed?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, see this: [Upload document to specific folder in a SharePoint Document library using WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312807/upload-document-to-specific-folder-in-a-sharepoint-document-library-using-webclie) and [Upload a file to SharePoint through the built-in web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-through-the-built-in-web-services)

Comment: thanks rubens for the quick reply. this sounds promising. will keep you posted.